# solve the differential equation $e^y(y'+1)=e^x$

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, differential

$e^y(y'+1)=e^x$

solve the differential equation

Comment: What if you write $u=e^y?$

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: If we set $y(x)=f(x)-x$, we have $y'+1=f'$ and the differential equation becomes $$ \frac{d}{dx} e^{f(x)} = e^{2x}, $$ from which $f(x)=\log(C+\frac{1}{2}e^{2x})$.

Comment: @amWhy I'm aware of that. What are you suggesting? I'm leaving a comment for future use, so that OP (and other users) can get into the habit of doing this. If you think I have down voted or voted to close simply because a post lacks proper formatting, then you are mistaken. I don't do that. I leave comments instead.

Comment: Brilliant solution by @JackD'Aurizio. Honestly, I wish it was posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the substitution $u=\mathrm{e}^y$, and then you'll get $y'\mathrm{e}^y=u'$. The equation now becomes
$$u'+u=\mathrm{e}^x$$
which its solution is
$$u=C\mathrm{e}^{-x}+\frac12\mathrm{e}^x$$
Finally $y$ would be $$y=\log{u}=\log{(C\mathrm{e}^{-x}+\frac12\mathrm{e}^x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another method called reduction to separation of variables is to spot when a differential equation is of the form $y'=f(Ax+By+c)$. Then you substitute $u=Ax+By+c$.

Here we have $$y'=e^{x-y}-1$$

Trying $u=x-y$, gives $u'=1-y'$, or $y'=1-u'$ so we have:

$$1-u'=e^u-1$$ or:

$$u'=2-e^u \implies \int\frac{du}{2-e^u}=x+c$$

Make the sub $v=2-e^u$, so $dv=-e^u du$ or $-e^{-u}dv=du$ or $$\frac{dv}{v-2}=du$$

Then $$\int \frac{dv}{v(v-2)}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{v-2}-\frac{1}{v} dv=x+c$$

Or $$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(v-2)-\ln(v))=x+c$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{e^u}{e^u-2}\right)=x+c$$

$$\frac{e^{x-y}}{e^{x-y}-2}=Ae^{2x}$$

$$\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x}-2e^y}=Ae^{2x}$$

$$e^{-x}=A\left(e^x-2e^{y}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(e^x-Be^{-x}\right)=e^y$$

Or to be consistent with the other solution:

$$y=\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}e^x+Ce^{-x}\right)$$